# How do i use ListPlot for making a graph from a list of numbers?

Tags: plotting, animation

I'm really new to Mathematica and I'm trying to graphical show my results of a program.

I have a list of numbers ***prikaz*** and i'm trying to make a graph out of those numbers.

```
prikaz = Table[ListPlot[rez[[i]], Joined -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, 102}, {-4, 4}}], {i,1000}];
ListAnimate[prikaz]
```

All i get is numbers in a list over time. I would like to get those numbers on a graph.

Comment: what do you get when you execute `rez[[1]]`?

Comment: Perhaps you just want `ListPlot[rez, PlotRange ->{-4, 4}]`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
rez = Range[100]/25;
prikaz = Table[ListPlot[{{i, rez[[i]]}}, Joined -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 102}, {-4, 4}}], {i, 100}];
ListAnimate[prikaz]
```

Or if `rez` is a collection of points, just use `{rez[[i]]}`:

```
rez = Map[{#, Sin[#]} &, Range[100]];
prikaz = Table[ListPlot[{rez[[i]]}, Joined -> False, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 102}, {-4, 4}}], {i, 100}];
ListAnimate[prikaz]
```